# Debugging - GNU ARM Bare Metal Development

Tags: eclipse, debugging, arm, gdb, segger-jlink

I am trying to debug a sample code given by Atmel. I have built the program successfully.

For debugging, I am using `eclipse` plus`gdb` plus `JlinkGDBServer` plus onboard Jtag.

Although the program can be downloaded to the board and is running well, I can't debug the program. Everytime I launch a debug session, the **JLinkGDBServer** will be **terminated** with an **error** as below:

[image]

Below are the messages shown in the console for each program termination:

**JLinkGDBServer**

```
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V4.96g Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V4.96g (DLL compiled Feb  6 2015 17:54:32)

-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      localhost only
Generate logfile:              on
Verify download:               on
Init regs on start:            on
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               on
Target connection timeout:     5 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 Cortex-A5
Target interface:              JTAG
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link OB-SAM3U128 V1 compiled Nov 28 2014 10:24:11
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 480300770
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...
J-Link found 1 JTAG device, Total IRLen = 4
JTAG ID: 0x4BA00477 (Cortex-A5)
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0xE59FF070)
Target interface speed set to 1000 kHz
Resetting target
Halting target CPU...
...Target halted (PC = 0x00000000)
PC = 00000000, CPSR = 000001D3 (SVC mode, ARM FIQ dis. IRQ dis.)
R0 = 00000004, R1 = 0031E0C3, R2 = 00016AAD, R3 = 00016965
R4 = 0031FFA0, R5 = C0542A08, R6 = C0512000, R7 = C051DA90
USR: R8 =C051DD80, R9 =410FC051, R10=C0512000, R11 =0031FF94, R12 =003020C0
     R13=BEBF5C70, R14=B6F12F1C
FIQ: R8 =9ABE0586, R9 =7E72A55E, R10=73DBFC6B, R11 =4F6717CF, R12 =05EDA809
     R13=5AC81462, R14=24683958, SPSR=370D2C67
SVC: R13=0031FF80, R14=00300620, SPSR=000001D3
ABT: R13=C0542B4C, R14=C000DC80, SPSR=A0000193
IRQ: R13=00320000, R14=80000053, SPSR=80000053
UND: R13=C0542B58, R14=C000DB60, SPSR=60000093
Reading all registers
Select auto target interface speed (1000 kHz)
Flash breakpoints enabled
Semi-hosting enabled (VectorAddr = 0x08)
Semihosting I/O set to TELNET and GDB Client
Downloading 15488 bytes @ address 0x00300000 - Verified OK
Writing register (PC = 0x00300080)
GDB closed TCP/IP connection
Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00300080 (Data = 0xF1080100)
Resetting target
Writing register (PC = 0x00300000)
Writing register (PC = 0x00300000)
Starting target CPU...
GDB closed TCP/IP connection
```

**arm-none-eabi-gdb**

```
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
```

**Semihosting and SWV**

```
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V4.96g - Terminal output channel
Connection closed by the GDB server.
```

The following is my debugging configuration:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Under the Run Commands, the commands in the box are as below:

```
target remote localhost:2331
monitor reset
load
mon reg pc = 0x300000
mon reg pc = 0x300000
end
```

I dont know what root cause is. I suspect that it is `arm-none-eabi-gdb` that causes the `JLinkGDBServer` to terminate with an exit code of `-1`.

Please help.

### Edit 1

FYI, I am using SAMA5D3x-EK development board.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this, I have a similar issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, I havent solved the problem yet. Currently, I am using IAR compiler to do my development under windows environment.

Comment: Working sample setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/550897ce1766e8df0b4ffcfdc17206f788d9f67f#baremetal-setup-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say, but looks like if the processor is having an exception while loading your code. I suggest to verify the load address of the sections of your ELF file, and review the linker settings of your project.

Hope it helps...